# Node is flagged, flag has node reference field, how to show list of referenced nodes to author

Tags: views, nodes, flags

This is a little convoluted, so I'll try to be as clear as possible by using concrete examples.

It's basically a "relevant job suggestion" system. It works like this:

- A "candidate" user creates a "CV" node.
- An "employer" creates "job" nodes.
- There is a flag set up that is attached to CVs.
- This flag has a node reference field.
- When an employer flags the CV, they choose a job node to reference (suggest)

I want to display a view of all job nodes suggested for that candidate - visible only to them (the author of the flagged node).

I hope that makes sense. I think the part I'm struggling with is getting the relationships & contextual filters right, so any pointers there would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would have an entity reference field for the user where their CV node is referenced. (Using rules on node creation). Helps in many ways.

In views, the contextual filter would be getting those CV nodes using the entity reference filter.

Then in the relationships, you would pick the appropriate flag and it should display the relevant job postings.

I'll test this tomorrow as its very similar to something i did before. I might be off on the contextual filter but i think you should definitely use entity reference from the beginning.

Edit: I'm actually quite certain you should be able to do this without entity reference or rules. Filter the view using Job content type. Then two relationships, one for node authored and flag.